# Is ReSTful webservice really the answer in my case?

Tags: security, rest, enterprise, restful-authentication

Wondering if ReSTful webservice is really the answer in my case of Enterprise application where there are some security concerns such as avoiding man-in-the-middle attacks, ensuring that a trusted client is connecting, client being sure that it is indeed talking to the real server etc.

Is HTTPS the solution? Have read some concerns being raised about its adequacy and fitment, although with a not-so-strong background in IT/application security, don't quite understand, why so!

I see ReST being talked (/ raved) about, and being projected as The-thing, and do see its adoption picking up, by can't seem to understand why the security thing isn't such a big concern, and if it is, what can be done about it.

Comment: What are your concerns about HTTPS?

Comment: @darrel-miller, have clarified my question further. Honestly, I don't know if HTTPS is adequate or not, as I just started reading up on ReST, and surprisingly the text doesn't talk anything about security. I'm unable to wrap my head around, how can one talk of exposing customer-list, customer-detail, orders-list, order-details over HTTP, even if it is for an enterprise intranet. Which leads me to believe that the text was a simple introduction, and there's a lot more to understand.

Comment: Have a thorough read about HTTPS and SSL/TLS to satisfy your worries about the protocol. Darrel's implied point is (I'm assuming) that HTTPS will likely satisfy your security requirements, and I'd be in agreement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are really serious about securing your service and avoiding man-in-the-middle attacks you should issue certificates to your clients and only accept requests that are signed with those certificates. It is more work for you and for your clients, but in an Enterprise setting, the extra effort may be worth it. It is definitely an option that is worth looking into.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box you are not going to have any type of message level security, and you would need to leverage HTTPS to do transport level security.

I have seen people attempt to use signed atom feeds, but its nothing to the level of the WS-* stack that comes with SOAP.

Comment: thanks for answering. Between posting my question and now, I've done some more reading, and thus can appreciate your response. Some have suggested OAuth2.0 to be the answer, and the designer/inventor of OAuth goes on to claim shortcomings of OAuth2.0 on his blog. My current understanding is that OAuth2.0 constructs (all of which I don't understand, yet), along with SSL, seems to address all current security concerns. However, is that the only solution, or are there other ways ? Large scale SSL certificate mgt/admin over time, seems to be rather challenging operation.